# Access blocked: Authorization Error. Google Auth when I send a link of my app to people

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

[image]You can't sign in from this screen because this app doesn't comply with Google's secure browser policy

Answer (score 1):

you need to open the authorization window in the default browser on the device

it sounds like you are trying to use a web view